# Consolas: Straight Quotes

Tags: xetex, listings, typewriter

I am using the `listings`-Package to display code. As I am using The Consolas Font as the Monotype-Default I expected straight quotes which isn't the case (check my MWE)

```
 \documentclass[a4paper]{article}
 \usepackage{listings}
 \usepackage{polyglossia}
 \setdefaultlanguage[]{english}

 \setmonofont[Ligatures=TeX]{Consolas}

  \lstset{frame=single}

  \begin{document}
  \begin{lstlisting}
  "some code to try"
  \end{lstlisting}

  \end{document}
```

Can Anyone help How to get straight quotes?
[image]

Comment: `listings` doesn't use the monospaced font by default, add `basicstyle=\ttfamily` to `\lstset`.

Comment: That does not work @TorbjørnT.  Is it because I use XeLaTex?

Comment: After testing I see that it still does not produce straight quotes, but it should at least be using Consolas after adding that. Given that Consolas should give straight quotes, I don't know why the quotes appear as they do, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually caused by `Ligatures=TeX`, which causes `fontspec` to automatically convert a  `"` to curly quotes, it appears. Further, as I mentioned in a comment, `listings` does not use the monotype font by default, so to actually use Consolas in the listings, add `basicstyle=\ttfamily` to `lstset`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[]{english}

\setmonofont{Consolas}

\lstset{frame=single,basicstyle=\ttfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
"some code to try"
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly thanks! @Torbjørn T. Another question: What is the difference between \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text} and the Ligatures=TeX?

Comment: @Kathiieee Nothing, see the `fontspec` manual. I quote: '*Mapping enables a XeTeX text-mapping scheme, shown in Example 43.
Using the `tex-text` mapping is also equivalent to writing `Ligatures=TeX`.*'