# How can I get straight quotes in pseudocode?

Tags: punctuation, pseudocode

The quotes in pseudocode currently look like this:

[image]

How can I get quotes that look more like a programming environment and less as if I just typed it with MS Word?

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts} % nice math rendering
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    This is a 'samle' with some "quotes".

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $a \gets \Call{map}{~}$
            \State $a['x'] \gets 42$
            \State $a["x"] \gets 1337$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{Algorithmus von Stoer und Wanger}
    \label{alg:seq1}
    \end{algorithm}
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

### Related questions

The question was already answered for some other environments:

- [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529/5645): It seems as if we can get straight quotes with `\textquotedbl` and `\textquotesingle`, but I want straight quotes for all algorithmic environments without having to fiddle around in my pseudocode
- [Consolas: Straight Quotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/144396/5645): This is for listings
- [How can I get straight double quotes in listings?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/166790/5645)
- [Straight quotes in tabbing](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172826/5645)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have the straight quotes, provided you use some tricks.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{etoolbox} % for the trick

% setup algorithmic to use straight quotes
\AtBeginEnvironment{algorithmic}{\useupquotes}

% define the command that activates the quotes and redefines them
\newcommand{\useupquotes}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\'\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\algoupquote
  \begingroup\lccode`\~=`\"\lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\algoupquotes
  \catcode`\'=\active\catcode`\"=\active
}

% Customize here (\mbox is necessary because of math mode;
% if needed in subscripts, use \text instead)
\newcommand{\algoupquote}{\mbox{\textquotesingle}}
\newcommand{\algoupquotes}{\mbox{\char`\"}}

\begin{document}
Look at Algorithm~\ref{some} for seeing the quotes.

\begin{algorithm}[htp]
\begin{algorithmic}
\State $a['x'] \gets 42$
\State $a["x"] \gets 1337$
\end{algorithmic}
\caption{Some algorithm}\label{some}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here's the active character approach, also using `textcomp`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdftex,active,tightpage]{preview}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{2mm}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts} % nice math rendering
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\let\svalgorithm\algorithm
\catcode`'=\active
\catcode`"=\active
\def\quoteactive{\catcode`'=\active\def'{\makebox{\textquotesingle}}}
\def\qquoteactive{\catcode`"=\active\def"{\makebox{\textquotedbl}}}
\catcode`'=12
\catcode`"=12
\def\algorithm{\quoteactive\qquoteactive\svalgorithm}

\begin{document}
\begin{preview}
    This is a 'sample' with some "quotes"{} or ``quotes''.

    \begin{algorithm}[H]
        \begin{algorithmic}
            \State $a \gets \Call{map}{~}$
            \State $a['x'] \gets 42$
            \State $a["x"] \gets 1337$
        \end{algorithmic}
    \caption{Algorithmus von Stoer und Wanger}
    \label{alg:seq1}
    \end{algorithm}
Restored? ' and ", ``quotations'' or `quotations'
\end{preview}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which is exactly the same approach I used.

Comment: @egreg Did you post first?  If so, I'll remove mine.

Comment: Don't; it's a different implementation, without `etoolbox`.

Comment: Well, I take it as a compliment to be accused of thinking like @egreg  ;^)

Answer (score 1):

You could probably make the quotes active, but I suggest wrapping them in a macro (a reference would be given in [Straight quotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/52529/5764)):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % this is needed for umlauts
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}    % this is needed for correct output of umlauts in pdf
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsfonts} % nice math rendering
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\upquotetype}{}
\newcommand{\upquote@aux}[1]{\text{\upquotetype}#1\text{\upquotetype}}
\newcommand{\upquotesingle}{\renewcommand{\upquotetype}{\textquotesingle}\upquote@aux}
\newcommand{\upquotedouble}{\renewcommand{\upquotetype}{\textquotedbl}\upquote@aux}

\begin{document}
This is a 'sample' with some "quotes".

\begin{algorithm}[H]
  \begin{algorithmic}
    \State $a[\upquotesingle{x}] \gets 42$
    \State $a[\upquotedouble{x}] \gets 1337$
  \end{algorithmic}
  \caption{Some algorithm}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```